# C# Sharepoint Online 401 Error: OAuth Authentication with CSOM API

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

We have a authentication problem with sharepoint online.
We use the Office365 authentication and CSOM API for c#.
When calling the 'ExecuteQuery' function, we get an 401 - exception (not authorized).

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var service = Office365OAuthTool.Authenticate(new Benutzer(new UnitOfWork()), true);
                string value = "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/lab";
                var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(value, service.AccessToken);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Tracing.Tracer.LogError(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

the app authorization has been configured via Azure.

However, authentification using username & password works.

Additional infos

1. User log in with Office365 credentials
2. We then cache the resulting token
3. We then use that token for the SharePoint login (We don´t use 'AppOnly')
4. We use the Office365 autenthication for EWS successfully